# Time-Complexity of recursive function

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I'm having some trouble determining the time complexity of this recursive function in terms of Big-O notation.

```java
double expRecursive(double x, int n) {
    if (n <= 4) {
        return expIterativ(x, n);
    }

    return expRecursive(x, n/2) *
           expRecursive(x, (n + 1)/2);
}
```

(The time complexity of the method expIterative is O(n))

Is the recurrence relation of expRecursive() T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n?

If this is the case I suppose T(n) = O(nlogn) after applying the master theorem?

My biggest problem is coming up with the correct recurrence relation...

Comment: Are you asking about how long it takes to run, or how big its output is?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Looks like O(log(n)) to me but it's rather ambiguous because `expIterativ`'s behavior on negative numbers is unclear. If it only does work from `0 < n <= 4` then it's constant time and you're left with 2*log(n) == O(log(n)). I assume this function is always called with positive numbers.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Yes, expIterative only works for n >= 0. But I still can't understand how to make a recurrence relation T(n) = aT(n/b) + n^c  with expRecursive.

Comment: Can someone help me to understand how to write the recurrence relation T(n) = aT(n/b) + n^c? :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the recurrence relation, it helps to first annotate the code:

```
double expRecursive(double x, int n) {
    if (n <= 4) {
        return expIterativ(x, n);       // O(1) since n is bounded
    }

    return expRecursive(x, n/2)         // T(n/2)
           *                            // O(1)
           expRecursive(x, (n + 1)/2);  // T(n/2)
}
```

So the recurrence relation is

```
T(n) = O(1),              for 0 <= n <= 4
T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) + O(1), for n > 4
```

which has the solution `T(n) ∈ Ө(n)`.

Comment: Why is the annotation of return expIterative(x, n) O(1)? Is this because n is bounded as you said and does not depend on n from expRecursive(x, n)? This is a little hard for me to understand since the method expIterative(x, n) itself is O(n).

Comment: @TheCoder The annotatation of the *multiplication* is O(1). The annotation for the recursive calls are both `T(n/2)`.

Comment: Would the annotation for return expIterative(x,n) be O(1) no matter what the specific method has as time complexity as it is bounded? Let's say if expIterative(x, n) was O(n^2), would it still be O(1) as in the annotation you made?

Comment: @TheCoder Oh sorry, I misread your first comment. Yes, since `n` is bounded, it doesn't matter what `expIterative` does. After all, the upper bound for the number of execution steps of `expIterative` (as called from this method) is independent of `n`. (I'm implicitly assuming it's also independent of `x`.)